# Can I change my Italian work permit to a blue card?

Tags: working-visas, blue-card

I am from outside the EU. I came to Italy to study and I found a job as a software engineer. My salary is  more than 28,000 euro per year, but my resident permit type is Lavoro subordinato. Based on italian regulation a salary above 26,000 euro is eligible for blue card. How should I get it?